# VideoJS - Remove Player and keep only video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I just started using videojs because it is the only way I can play .M3U8 files inside a browser but it comes it with its own player so I can't put my own buttons to it. I just want to keep the video tag and remove the rest of the player. I am not able to find anything on google about this

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <video id="my_video_1">
        <source src="https://mplayer.sbs/caching/OTA3OTk=.m3u8"
            type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>

    <script>
        var player = videojs('my_video_1');
        player.play();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove [components](https://videojs.com/guides/components/) including controls from the player by specifying the player's child components:

```
var player = videojs('my_video_1', {children: ['MediaLoader']})
```